# need awk script for some xml node concat

Tags: xml, awk

i'm new to awk and need some assistance with a simple awk script to strip all the character metrics and concat the attributes to squash the XML by quite a bit.

input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <page>
        <block bbox="270 163.717 363.262 224.155">
            <line bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669">
                <span bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="16.02">
                    <char bbox="270 200.519 284.425 224.155" c="f"/>
                    <char bbox="284.43 200.519 291.082 224.155" c="o"/>
                    <char bbox="291.087 200.519 297.74 224.155" c="o"/>
                </span>
            </line>
            <line bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155">
                <span bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="19.98">
                    <char bbox="270 200.519 284.425 224.155" c="b"/>
                    <char bbox="284.43 200.519 291.082 224.155" c="a"/>
                    <char bbox="291.087 200.519 297.74 224.155" c="r"/>
                </span>
            </line>
        </block>
    </page>
</document>
```

desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <page>
        <block bbox="270 163.717 363.262 224.155">
            <line bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669">
                <span bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="16.02">foo</span>
            </line>
            <line bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155">
                <span bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="19.98">bar</span>
            </line>
        </block>
    </page>
</document>
```

thanks!

Comment: -1 just use XSLT instead of asking how to do things in the worst possible way. Awk! Not even Perl! WTF.

Comment: xslt is the right way to do this and i'm aware of that. part of this was to play around with gawk. though this grep will do exactly what i need, too: `[\r\n\s]*<char .* c="(.)".*/>[\r\n\s]*` => `\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
awk '{if (index($0, "<char") == 0) print $0}' xmlfile
```

**EDIT**: Try this script:

```
gawk '{ if (index($0, "<char") > 0) {mat = gensub(/.*c=\"(.*)\".*/, "\\1", "g"); 
                                     tmp = tmp mat;} 
        else if (index($0, "</span>") > 0)
              { print gensub(/(.*)<\/span>/, "\\1", "g") "  " tmp "\n" $0;
                tmp = "";} 
        else print $0 }' xmlfile
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <page>
        <block bbox="270 163.717 363.262 224.155">
            <line bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669">
                <span bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="16.02">
                  foo
                </span>
            </line>
            <line bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155">
                <span bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="19.98">
                  bar
                </span>
            </line>
        </block>
    </page>
</document>
```

Comment: this only strips the chars, i actually need to accumulate their "c" attributes, and output that buffer in place of all the char nodes. see my desired ouput.

Comment: In that case awk is probably the wrong tool. Awk is meant to process lines - I know there are ways to get it to keep some kind of state but it's painful. I would use Python and BeautifulSoup to do this. It would be pretty simple.

Comment: I updated with another awk answer, but @anubhava 's is probably better since it doesn't have newlines.

Comment: Updated again - almost equivalent now, one less newline, and not dependent on the order of attributes on the `<char>` tag or anything like that.

Comment: thats pretty close actually.

what i got so far is `{if (match($0, /<char/)) {match($0, c="(.)"/, ary) print ary[1]} else print $0}` but the chars are newline separated. this is good enough to get me started. thx.

Comment: Yeah .. just added some more ugliness in there to have the right spacing as well if you need it to be spaced properly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

XML parsing is not recommended using standard unix shell utilities. It requires a proper XML parser to do that.

Using awk following command gets you your output (assuming `c=` attribute is always comes at 2nd position in `<char>` XML tag:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\""} /<char /{tag = tag $4;}
/<\/span>/{print tag; tag="";} !/<char /' file.xml
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <page>
        <block bbox="270 163.717 363.262 224.155">
            <line bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669">
                <span bbox="270 163.717 274.453 182.669" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="16.02">
foo
                </span>
            </line>
            <line bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155">
                <span bbox="270 200.519 363.262 224.155" font="Helvetica-Bold" size="19.98">
bar
                </span>
            </line>
        </block>
    </page>
</document>
```

Comment: i realize this, but the input is uniform, not arbitrary. otherwise i'd def go that route. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are employing awk inspite of being aware that XML 
ought to be processed by proper tooling. Anyway, it must be mentioned that this really is a case for [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt).

With [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) 6 (or higher), a command like this

```
java -jar saxon.jar input.xml stylesheet.xslt
```

produces the desired result by means of a stylesheet like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="span">
    <span>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="char/@c">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```